# Exceptionhandling "only numbers allowed", error before I hit enter. Why?

Tags: java, swing

When I run the program I get the pop-up box, and when I enter a number in either number1 or number2 the exceptionhandling gives me the "only numbers allowed" error before I get to hit the "enter"-key. It keeps doing that until I've filled a number in both textfields. It is not supposed to give me errors unless I put other than numbers in the textfields.
Also. I can't convert from CM to INCH twice, it will give me the error again. I have to switch between converting from CM to INCH and INCH to CM.
It converts fine, so the problem must be something with the setup of the exceptionhandling? It's like it reads the textfield before I hit enter, and therefore it gives me an error because no number has been insert.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you in advance!

//Daniel

I've 2 classes.

**Code for class 1:**

```
package inchcm;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class InchCM extends JFrame {

    private JTextField num1 = new JTextField(8);
    private JTextField num2 = new JTextField(8);
    private JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel l2 = new JLabel();

    public InchCM() {


        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //panel 1 med GridLayout (2,0) til 2 x JTextField(8).
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        p1.add(new JLabel(""));
        p1.add(num1);
        p1.add(new JLabel(""));
        p1.add(num2);


        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        p2.add(new JLabel(" Inches"));
        p2.add(l1);
        p2.add(new JLabel(" Centimeters"));
        p2.add(l2);


        add(p1, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.WEST);


        num1.addKeyListener(
                new KeyAdapter() {

                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                        try {

                            double nummer1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText());
                            double nummer2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText());

                            Udregning udr = new Udregning(nummer1, nummer2);


                            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                                num2.setText(String.format("%.2f", udr.inchtocm()));
                            }                            
                        } 
                        //end tal i et af JTextFieldsne.
                        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            System.out.println(ex);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Only numbers allowed \nTry again",
                                    "Input error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                });



        num2.addKeyListener(
                new KeyAdapter() {                    

                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                        try {
                            //objekt af num1 og num2.
                            double nummer1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText());
                            double nummer2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText());

                            Udregning udr = new Udregning(nummer1, nummer2);


                            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                                num1.setText(String.format("%.2f", udr.cmtoinch()));
                            }                            
                        } 

                        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            System.out.println(ex);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Only numbers allowed \nTry againn",
                                    "Input error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        InchCM frame = new InchCM();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("InchCM");
        frame.setSize(300, 130);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Code for class 2:
"Calculation class"**

```
package inchcm;

public class Udregning {

    private double num1 = 0;
    private double num2 = 0;

    Udregning() {
    }

    Udregning(double newnum1, double newnum2) {
        setnum1(newnum1);
        setnum2(newnum2);
    }

    private void setnum1(double newnum1) {
        num1 = newnum1;
    }

    private void setnum2(double newnum2) {
        num2 = newnum2;
    }

    public double inchtocm() {
        double result;
        result = num1 * 2.54;
        return result;
    }

    public double cmtoinch() {
        double result;
        result = num2 * .39;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use keyListeners, ever. Instead, use higher level api like JFormattedTextField or at the lowest, JTextField + DocumentFilter

Answer (score 1):

As I learned here recently myself, there is no need for a `KeyListener` to achieve this behavior. You should add an `ActionListener` to the `JTextField`, which will be triggered when ENTER is pushed inside the textfield.

If you want to trigger an action for another key then the ENTER key, you should use keybindings instead of a `KeyListener`. See the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score -1):

Your try catch block is executed everytime the KeyReleased event is fired - i.e. every keypress.  You need to change it to check for VK_ENTER before attempting to parse the input number:

```
try {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        double nummer1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText());
        double nummer2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText());

        Udregning udr = new Udregning(nummer1, nummer2);
        num2.setText(String.format("%.2f", udr.inchtocm()));
    }                            
} 
//end tal i et af JTextFieldsne.
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Only numbers allowed \nTry again",
            "Input error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: I was going to post this solution =]

Comment: @sHIRKIT LOL - there are only the quick, the dead and the cows }:)

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the problem, now I can enter a number without getting exceptionhandling.
But there is another problem:

When I put in a number in "number1" and hits <enter> to convert INCH to CM it give me the error "only numbers allowed". I have to fill both number1 and number2 before I am allowed to hit enter. Why?

Comment: @Daniel because you are parsing both numbers.  `Double.parseDouble()` will raise a `NumberFormatException` if you attempt to parse an invalid number.  Test that `num1.getText()` and `num2.getText()` are not null or empty strings before trying to parse them.

Comment: @mcfinnigan how do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

I can agree with answer of @mcfinnigan, but furthermore in the event handler of `num1` you should not react on `num2`. If you want to update on every key:

```
 num1.addKeyListener(
            new KeyAdapter() {

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                    try {
                        double nummer1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText());

                        // Synchronize both fields:
                        try {
                            double nummer2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText());

                            Udregning udr = new Udregning(nummer1, nummer2);
                            //if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                                num2.setText(String.format("%.2f", udr.inchtocm()));
                            //}                            
                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex2) { }


                    } 
                    //end tal i et af JTextFieldsne.
                    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Only numbers allowed \nTry again",
                                "Input error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: One should use a `DocumentListener` and not a `KeyListener`

Comment: @Robin in general true because thus one catches **any** change. But here everything is on the interactive level: a user is typng and an error dialog may result from that.